# a c++ Google chrome event listener

Tags: c++, browser, google-chrome

can anyone help me on how to connect to google chrome. i would like to build a standalone c++ application(probably a dll) that would list events done by the browser.Probably like the BHO implementation of IE.

can anyone give the first thing or steps to do about it?!

thanks alot:) help much appreciated

PS: i already have known that google chrome is supporting MSSA.

Answer (score 0):

Via the AutomationProvider:

`src\chrome\browser\automation\automation_provider.cc /.h`